# spring boot thymeleaf does not work with LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, mobile-website

I am working with spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE, using spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf. And I have two version of pages for PC and Mobile phone.

Here is a simple version of my project structure
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM6Db.jpg)

I would like to have the site automatically detect the PC browser and Mobile phone browser so that it can map the same requesting URL to different pages according to the type of the browsers

The html file is very simple as the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is from PC web browser</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code of my controller.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String mainDefault(){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String main(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

To detect the device I wrote the following configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver liteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver resolver = new LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver(viewResolver);
        resolver.setNormalPrefix("web/");
        resolver.setMobilePrefix("mobile/");
        resolver.setTabletPrefix("web/");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setEnableFallback(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(".HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor = new DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor();
        SitePreferenceHandlerInterceptor sitePreferenceHandlerInterceptor = new SitePreferenceHandlerInterceptor();
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
        registry.addInterceptor(deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor);
        registry.addInterceptor(sitePreferenceHandlerInterceptor);
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }
}
```

Then when I tried to run the Application. I always get the following error. It seems it can map to the right resource which is [/templates/web/home.html]. But it always say *Could not open ServletContext resource [/templates/web/home.html]*

If I visit from a mobile browser it map to [/templates/mobile/home.html] which is also correct.

Can any one help me? Thank you in advance.

```
2018-04-19 17:18:57.040 ERROR 17732 --- [nio-9020-exec-9] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-9020-exec-9] Exception processing template "web/home": An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/templates/web/home.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/templates/web/home.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
```

.........

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/templates/web/home.html]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:159) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted

2018-04-19 17:18:57.047 DEBUG 17732 --- [nio-9020-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Error rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView@139a953a] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/templates/web/home.html]")
```

Comment: You are trying to do too much. Spring Boot already configures all of that for you. Just remove your own configuration. In your `application.properties` add values for the `spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.normalPrefix` (and `tabletPrefix` and `mobilePrefix`) and restart your application.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to configure something that is already being [configured for you](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mobile/blob/master/spring-mobile-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/mobile/autoconfigure/DeviceDelegatingViewResolverAutoConfiguration.java).

1. Make sure you have the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` and that you have the `spring-mobile-autoconfguration` in your list of dependencies.

**NOTE:** I assume you are using the snapshot builds so that you are compatible with regards to Spring and Spring Boot version.

2. Remove your `Config` class
3. Add the following to your `application.properties`

   ```
   spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.normalPrefix=web/
   spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.tabletPrefix=web/
   spring.thymeleaf
   ```
4. Restart your application

Comment: Thank you,  M. Deinum,

What you said works for spring boot 1.5.x version. And I tested it with spring boot 1.5.8. It works well.

As I mentioned in the question. I am using spring boot 2.0.1 in which Auto-configuration and dependency management for Spring Mobile has been removed according to the following guide. That means I have to configure it by myself.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: And if you read my answer I state you should include the `spring-mobile-autoconfiguration` project. It has been removed from Spring Boot and included in Spring Mobile. I also stated in my answer that I assume you use a version of Spring Mobile compatible with Spring Boot 2 (and thus Spring 5) and as such are using the latest SNAPSHOT builds of Spring Mobile.